# linux zip and exclude dir via bash/shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zip

I am trying to write a bash/shell script to zip up a specific folder and ignore certain sub-dirs in that folder.

This is the folder I am trying to zip "**sync_test5**":

[image]

My bash script generates an ignore list ([based on](https://superuser.com/a/312302/220765)) and calls the zip function like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BASE_DIR="/home/www-data/public_html"
SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR="sync_test5"
SYNC_WEB_ROOT_IGNORE_DIR="dir_to_ignore dir2_to_ignore"

ignorelist=""
if [ "$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_IGNORE_DIR" != "" ];
then
    for ignoredir in $SYNC_WEB_ROOT_IGNORE_DIR
    do
        ignorelist="$ignorelist $SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$ignoredir/**\*"
    done
fi

FILE="$SYNC_BACKUP_DIR/$DATETIMENOW.website.zip"
cd $SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BASE_DIR;
zip -r $FILE $SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR -x $ignorelist >/dev/null
echo "Done"
```

Now this script runs without error, however it is ***not*** ignoring/excluding the dirs I've specified.

So, I had the shell script output the command it tried to run, which was:

```
zip -r 12-08-2014_072810.website.zip sync_test5 -x  sync_test5/dir_to_ignore/**\* sync_test5/dir2_to_ignore/**\*
```

Now If I run the above command directly in putty like this, it works:

[image]

So, why doesn't my shell script exclude working as intended? the command that is being executed is identical (in shell and putty directly).

Comment: I tried using absolute path also (without using the `cd` command) and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because backslash quotings in a variable after word splitting are not evaluated.

If you have `a='123\4'`, `echo $a` would give

```
123\4
```

But if you do it directly like `echo 123\4`, you'd get

```
1234
```

Clearly the arguments you pass with the variable and without the variables are different.

You probably just meant to not quote your argument with backslash:

```
ignorelist="$ignorelist $SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$ignoredir/***"
```

Btw, what actual works is a non-evaluated glob pattern:

```
zip -r 12-08-2014_072810.website.zip sync_test5 -x 'sync_test5/dir_to_ignore/***' 'sync_test5/dir2_to_ignore/***'
```

You can verify this with

```
echo zip -r 12-08-2014_072810.website.zip sync_test5 -x  sync_test5/dir_to_ignore/**\* sync_test5/dir2_to_ignore/**\*
```

And this is my suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash

SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BASE_DIR="/home/www-data/public_html"
SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR="sync_test5"
SYNC_WEB_ROOT_IGNORE_DIR=("dir_to_ignore" "dir2_to_ignore")

IGNORE_LIST=()
if [[ -n $SYNC_WEB_ROOT_IGNORE_DIR ]]; then
    for IGNORE_DIR in "${SYNC_WEB_ROOT_IGNORE_DIR[@]}"; do
        IGNORE_LIST+=("$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$IGNORE_DIR/***")  ## "$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$IGNORE_DIR/*"  perhaps is enough?
    done
fi

FILE="$SYNC_BACKUP_DIR/$DATETIMENOW.website.zip"  ## Where is $SYNC_BACKUP_DIR set?
cd "$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BASE_DIR";
zip -r "$FILE" "$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR" -x "${IGNORE_LIST[@]}" >/dev/null
echo "Done"
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the explanation and suggestion. I tried it and its still not working.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful little script. As I have it, the ignored directories are still being created, just not with contents. https://github.com/MikeiLL/managed-directory-compressor

Comment: @MikeiLL Try to add the directory itself to the ignore list as well e.g. `IGNORE_LIST+=("$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$IGNORE_DIR/***" "$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$IGNORE_DIR")` or `IGNORE_LIST+=("$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$IGNORE_DIR" "$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$IGNORE_DIR/***")`. Or maybe just having `IGNORE_LIST+=("$SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$IGNORE_DIR")` would work, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up with:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script zips a directory, excluding specified files, types and subdirectories.
#  while zipping the directory it excludes hidden directories and certain file types

[[ "`/usr/bin/tty`" == "not a tty" ]] && . ~/.bash_profile

DIRECTORY=$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: managed_directory_compressor /your-directory/ zip-file-name"
else
  DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS=${1%/}
  ZIPPED_FILE="$2.zip"

  COMPRESS_IGNORE_FILE=("\.git" "*.zip" "*.csv" "*.json" "gulpfile.js" "*.rb" "*.bak" "*.swp" "*.back" "*.merge" "*.txt" "*.sh" "bower_components" "node_modules") 
  COMPRESS_IGNORE_DIR=("bower_components" "node_modules")

  IGNORE_LIST=("*/\.*" "\.* "\/\.*"")
  if [[ -n $COMPRESS_IGNORE_FILE ]]; then
      for IGNORE_FILES in "${COMPRESS_IGNORE_FILE[@]}"; do
          IGNORE_LIST+=("$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS/$IGNORE_FILES/*")  
      done
      for IGNORE_DIR in "${COMPRESS_IGNORE_DIR[@]}"; do
          IGNORE_LIST+=("$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS/$IGNORE_DIR/")
      done
  fi

  zip -r "$ZIPPED_FILE" "$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS" -x "${IGNORE_LIST[@]}" # >/dev/null
  # echo zip -r "$ZIPPED_FILE" "$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS" -x "${IGNORE_LIST[@]}" # >/dev/null
  echo $DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS "compressed as" $ZIPPED_FILE.
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few trial and error, I have managed to fix this problem by changing this line:

```
ignorelist="$ignorelist $SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$ignoredir/**\*"
```

to:

```
ignorelist="$ignorelist $SYNC_WEB_ROOT_BACKUP_DIR/$ignoredir/***"
```

*Not sure why this worked, but it does :)*

Comment: It's as how I suggested. I made the explanation about that.