# Zip with ignore within Bash script

Tags: git, bash, zip

Found a [wonderful little bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263199/linux-zip-and-exclude-dir-via-bash-shell-script) that I've [adapted](https://github.com/MikeiLL/managed-directory-compressor) to use for zip compressing *managed* directories, ignoring files like `bower_components`, `.git` and `node_modules`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script zips a directory, excluding specified files, types and subdirectories.
#  while zipping the directory it excludes hidden directories and certain file types

[[ "`/usr/bin/tty`" == "not a tty" ]] && . ~/.bash_profile

DIRECTORY=$(cd `dirname $0` && pwd)

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: managed_directory_compressor /your-directory/ zip-file-name"
else
  DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS=$1
  ZIPPED_FILE="$2.zip"
  COMPRESS_IGNORE_DIR=("\.git" "node_modules" "bower_components")

  IGNORE_LIST=("*/\.*" "\.* "\/\.*"")
  if [[ -n $COMPRESS_IGNORE_DIR ]]; then
      for IGNORE_DIR in "${COMPRESS_IGNORE_DIR[@]}"; do
          IGNORE_LIST+=("$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS/$IGNORE_DIR/***")  ## "$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS/$IGNORE_DIR/*"  perhaps is enough?
      done
  fi

  zip -r "$ZIPPED_FILE" "$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS" -x "${IGNORE_LIST[@]}" # >/dev/null
  echo zip -r "$ZIPPED_FILE" "$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS" -x "${IGNORE_LIST[@]}" # >/dev/null
  echo "Done"
fi
```

The only problem is that the directories I want to ignore are still being created, just empty.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zip-man-page says

> Note that currently the trailing / is needed for directories (as in
>
> ```
> zip -r foo . -i dir/
> ```
>
> to include directory dir).

So, likewise exclusion seems to work: Replacing the marked line in your script by

```
IGNORE_LIST+=("$DIRECTORY_TO_COMPRESS/$IGNORE_DIR/")
```

should do the trick.

(my zip is version 3.0 on Ubuntu-Linux)